# JSON writes one list element per line

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

Writing a `list` to a `JSON` file writes one element at per line.

How can I write a list to one line, maintaining its `dtype`?

---

`separators=(','...` is enforcing this (needed for separating `key-value` pairs). How can I make an exception clause for lists?

```
import json

my_list = [1, 2, 3]

data = {
  'my_list': my_list 
}

with open('test.json', 'w') as json:
    json.dump(data, json, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

**test.json**

```
data = {
    'my_list': [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3
               ],
    'another key': "val"
}
```

**Desired output**:

```
data = {
    'my_list': [1, 2, 3],
    'another key': "val"
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what output you expect? Neither ``my_list``, ``data``, nor JSON in general has a concept of ``dtype``s.

Comment: Note that if your problem is that the JSON is indented across several lines, don't request ``indent=4``.

Comment: My problem is with `separators=(','...` causing a line break, which it does correctly. However, I don't want it to do so for `list`s. `separators=(','...` is needed for separating `key-value` pairs.

Comment: ``separators=(',', ': ')`` is not causing the line breaks. Either way, if you want to have different separators depending on data type, then ``json`` is the wrong tool – and then JSON is likely the wrong format.

Comment: Where does ``'another key': "val"`` in the desired "actual"/output come from? It's not in the ``data``. And ``data = {...}`` isn't valid JSON either...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sorry that's just a crude example... but you have stated `separators` isn't at fault here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I am looking for, `YAML` is the best alternative. It allows you to write what would be `Python` `lists` on one line.